# Dúvida sobre RSS feed

Tags: php, rss, feed

Estou desenvolvendo uma página de `feed` para um blog `PHP` puro e me veio algumas dúvidas que não consegui encontrar as respostas.

- Os itens do feed devem ser exibidos por quanto tempo? Por exemplo, um post criado no ano passado ainda deve ser exibido no feed? Ou apenas dos ultimos x meses?
- Existe limite de itens em um rss feed? Caso exista, qual esse limite?
- É interessante separar o feed por categorias do blog? Ou apeas um único feed geral?

Comment: Cara alguns detalhes da pegunta não tenho conhecimento técnico para te falar, mas posso bolar uma resposta simples do ponto de vista do usuário se te interessar. Até pensei em escrever aqui mesmo no comentário, mas vai ficar maior que o limite de caracteres...

Comment: Me interesso sim @hugocsl. Estou desenvolvendo no momento por tentativa e erro e vendo se o feedburner aceita a leitura do meu feed haha.